# Choosing a renormalization point where the amplitude is not defined?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, renormalization

This [lecture note](http://fma.if.usp.br/%7Eburdman/QFT1/lecture_22.pdf) goes through the renormalization of the s-channel one-loop correction to the four-point function $\Gamma(s,t,u)$ in $\lambda \phi^4$-theory. It uses Pauli-Villars regularization, which includes expanding around $p^2=0$, i.e. $\; \Gamma(p^2) = \Gamma(0) + \widetilde{\Gamma}(p^2)$. $\; \widetilde{\Gamma}(p^2)$ can be shown to have the general solution of

$$\widetilde{\Gamma}(s) = 
 \begin{cases}
  \frac{i \lambda^2}{32\pi^2} \left( 2-2\sqrt{\frac{4m^2-s}{s}} \arctan{\left[ \sqrt{\frac{s}{4m^2-s}} \right]} \right) \; ; &0<s<4m^2 \\
  \frac{i \lambda^2}{32\pi^2} \left( 2+\sqrt{\frac{s-4m^2}{s}} \ln{\left[ \frac{\sqrt{s}-\sqrt{s-4m^2}}{\sqrt{s}+\sqrt{s-4m^2}} \right]} + i\pi \right)\; ; &s>4m^2 \\
  \frac{i \lambda^2}{32\pi^2} \left( 2+\sqrt{\frac{4m^2-s}{|s|}} \ln{\left[ \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{4m^2-s}-\sqrt{|s|}}{\sqrt{4m^2-s}+\sqrt{|s|}}} \right]} \right)\; ; &s<0 \; ,
 \end{cases}$$

where $s=(p_1+p_2)^2$. Here is my issue with this: next he chooses a renormalization point of $s_0 = 4m^2$, where the function is not defined, and even by inserting this point into the function, the two parts do not connect, due to the $+i \pi$ in the region $s>4m^2$. How do I make sense of this?

Comment: From $(22.52)$ of your document, it seems that the condition $s_0=4m^2$ is in fact $s_0 \stackrel{s_0 >4m^2}{\rightarrow} 4m^2$, so we are still in the physical region.

Comment: @JeanbaptisteRoux thank you - that would seem to make a lot more sense. I was also confused why he could 'arbitrarily' choose one of the regions.